# Prehistoric VS Prehistorical

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I know 'prehistoric' is the normally used term—as I found in the Google Ngram Viewer—but as 'prehistorical' is found in dictionaries too, I was wondering whether the latter would sound more acceptable, so to speak, in certain contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford dictionary has it: the Cambridge and Collins Dictionaries do not.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prehistorical) sums it up quite nicely by having an entry for **prehistoric** that contains the text

> variants: *or less commonly **prehistorical***

**prehistorical** is certainly a valid word, but I can't think of any circumstances where I would use it rather than **prehistoric**.

This [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prehistoric%2C%20prehistorical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprehistoric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprehistorical%3B%2Cc0) shows clearly that uages of prehistorical are very uncommon.

Comment: I think it's similar to *ironic* and *ironical*. You can say either one, but *ironic* is certainly more common.

Comment: @godel9: ironical is proportionally a lot more common than prehistorical, and used to be the preferred version until about 1935. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ironic%2C+ironical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cironic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cironical%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Interesting! I remember visiting an English class in a French high school in the 1990's where they were teaching the word "ironical," and I remember thinking it was a little odd, but I guess it's a little more common than I thought. :-)